# SMB server's behavior under NT Domain and Active Directory Domain

Tags: domain-controller, server-message-block

(1) If SMB server joined to the NT Domain, does the SMB server itself executes a user authentication by communicating to a Domain Controller? To do it, does SMB client need to send a Type3Message which has NTLM(v1, v2) response to the SMB server? That is, is it correct that the SMB client doesn't need to communicate to the Domain Controller?

(2) In the other hand, if SMB server joined to an Active Directory Domain, does SMB client need to send a authentication request to the Domain Controller with Kerberos? That is, does the SMB server not communicate to the Domain Controller? Instead, the SMB client needs to communicate to the Domain Controller, and needs to retrieve the ticket which is necessary for authorization, I guess. Is this correct?